# How to retrieve HLS streaming video URL?

Tags: ios, html, streaming, live, http-live-streaming

How to retrieve HLS streaming video URL for watching live streams with VLC? (actual path to media file). I used Wireshark to find URL of leave stream, but only can get this [path](http://213.202.212.58/hls/03/index.m3u8?md=8bPwZMHZb1HGu3OVofJ7cw&e=1441922937), which contains no link to video file.

Example of [stream](http://rus24.tv/sport_plus.html).

EDIT: I find the easiest way is to use the Firefox developer tools: Tools > Web Developer > Network, and watch the network requests made when a page is loaded. Then just see 'GET' requests to **M3U8** playlist file, the full path to playlist shown on the right pane, in the 'Filter URLs' box. Finally, put the discovered **M3U8** link into the standard **M3U** playlist file. It can be played on mpv Media Player (Linux), for example.

Answer (score 1):

A m3u8 file is an index file which contains urls for the  individual video streams inside it, generally as URI's to MPEG-2 transport segment files. These are basically 'chunks' of your video file.

For your example if you copy the link you have above and paste it into a standard Chrome browser, it should download rather than try to play the m3u8 file.

If you then select the downloaded file in your explorer or finder etc and open it with a text file you should be able to see the URI's to the individual 'ts' files in the m3u8 index file. For your example above this results in:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:41125
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXTINF:8.360,
41125.ts?md=8bPwZMHZb1HGu3OVofJ7cw&e=1441922937
#EXTINF:8.000,
41126.ts?md=8bPwZMHZb1HGu3OVofJ7cw&e=1441922937
#EXTINF:8.400,
41127.ts?md=8bPwZMHZb1HGu3OVofJ7cw&e=1441922937
#EXTINF:8.200,
41128.ts?md=8bPwZMHZb1HGu3OVofJ7cw&e=1441922937
#EXTINF:7.200,
41129.ts?md=8bPwZMHZb1HGu3OVofJ7cw&e=1441922937
```

Comment: Yes, I understand it contains chunks of the video file (similar with Adobe HDS streaming protocol for FLV video). Is it possible to recover URL to full MPEG-2 file?

Comment: @minto Yes, it's easy with a tool like `ffmpeg`. You can also download each  `.ts` segment individually and concatenate them later. HLS can also use variant playlist so be sure to get the playlist for your desired bitrate since using the master might make your stream switch based on bandwidth.

Comment: @aergistal These .ts are separate chunks of stream. In case of **live stream**, how to find source URL of a media stream? (not to segments of stream)

Comment: @minto - you mean to the file that was split into chunks originally? You can't get this from the m3u8 file as every site or video provider might have a different workflow and naming convention for their original files and for their chunks.

Comment: @minto The `m3u8` **is** the source URL. Since it's live there might not be a source file at all, for eg. if it's a re-broadcast of a satellite channel. If you want to see it in VLC use the "Open network" option and paste the `m3u8` URL.

Comment: I tried open m3u8 in VLC, but it can't play: `"Your input can't be opened: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'http://... .../hls/25/35501.ts'. Check the log for details."` (for every of 5 chunks)

Comment: @minto It's probably protected against cross-domain requests and plays only in their player.

Comment: @aergistal yes, thanks - that works fine. But how to download it? Do you know?

Comment: @MykhailoLysenko You download the playlist and all the segments then update the playlist if paths changed. Or you use another program like `ffmpeg` to download and remux them directly in another format, like MP4.

Comment: @aergistal yes, I tried that and that worked fine. The question is how to download all the segments automatically. I tried VLC player but it was able to save only 27 MB then it was always interrupting - that was just a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the link to the m3u8 into something like JDownloader2 and it will let you download the entire thing as one file.